# Display text in a div based on inner.HTML value of another div

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script:

```
  function showstatus()
  {
  var inputbedtwo = document.getElementById("bedtwostatus");
  var inputliving = document.getElementById("livingstatus");
  var inputkitchen = document.getElementById("kitchenstatus");
  if(inputbedtwo.innerHTML == "A"){
    document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Danger";
  }
  else if(inputliving.innerHTML == "A"){
    document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Danger";
  }
  else if(inputkitchen.innerHTML == "A"){
    document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Danger";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Normal";}
  }
```

The trouble with this is that it is only outputting Normal text in `<span id="statustop"></span>`

When the status is changing to "A", it does not output Danger.

I would like it to output Danger when status is "A".

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the markup ?

Comment: I think the problem is in HTML code, could you share it with us?

Comment: We don't have enough information. We don't know when or how this function is called, and in response to what. Do some debugging; is the function being entered when you think it is? Are the values what you think they are? Basic debugging can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the title, I Added three divs with A,A,B as their innerHTMl and it works fine.

Now if you could include your markup that would be helpful to find the problem, if not just take a look at what i did here and adjust your own.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click',showstatus);

function showstatus() {
    var inputbedtwo = document.getElementById("bedtwostatus");
    var inputliving = document.getElementById("livingstatus");
    var inputkitchen = document.getElementById("kitchenstatus");
    if (inputbedtwo.innerHTML == "A") {
        document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Danger";
    } else if (inputliving.innerHTML == "A") {
        document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Danger";
    } else if (inputkitchen.innerHTML == "A") {
        document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Danger";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Normal";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="bedtwostatus">A</div>
<div id="livingstatus">A</div>
<div id="kitchenstatus">B</div>
<span id="statustop"></span>
<button id="btn">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is working fine. I will try and troubleshoot it and see when the function is being called. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a change event.

```html
<input id="bedtwo" type="text" name="" value="">

<span id="statustop"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var inputbedtwo = document.getElementById("bedtwo");

  inputbedtwo.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    if (this.value === "A") {
      document.getElementById("statustop").innerHTML = "Danger";
    }
  });
</script>
```